# Does the DCOS installation process work the same with an existing Mesos installation or do we need to start from scratch?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

We have an existing Apache Mesos cluster and want to try DCOS in its shiny new Open Source form. However, it would be painful to do a destructive re-install of DCOS. So is it possible to just 'overlay' DCOS on an existing Mesos installation? Would any of the steps change in the DCOS installation guide or could the installer detect the existing Mesos and install DCOS components over it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can simply overlay DC/OS on top of your Mesos cluster. There are multiple reasons for that; one of those is that configuration is for Mesos and marathon is done differently in DC/OS as it is done for Mesos clusters.

Comment: Any advances on "I don't think so"?